# Turn a list into a distinct list and map indices

Tags: kotlin, distinct-values

I have a List of Objects, and I want to turn it into a distinct list while mapping all indices to the new indices.

Example:

List: `["a", "b", "a", "d"]` -> `["a", "b", "d"]`

Map:

```
{
  0: 0, //0th index of original list is now 0th index of distinct list
  1: 1,
  2: 0, //2nd index of original list is now 0th index of distinct list
  3: 2  //3rd index of original list is now 2th index of distinct list
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this with a one-liner or with a fairly simple solution in kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following expression will do that:

```
val p = listOf("a", "b", "a", "d").let {
  val set = it.distinct().mapIndexed { i, v -> v to i }.toMap()
  it.mapIndexed { i, v -> i to set.getValue(v) }
}.toMap()
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer! I'm wondering: Is there a more computationally efficient way to doing this? (as using `indexOf` in a loop can get very slow for large lists)

Comment: You are right. We may update `set` variable to map from string to index - it will be faster. I'll update the answer

Comment: @EugenePetrenko using set[v] (get operator) instead of getValue would make it even more beautiful :)

Comment: You are right, but the type of the map would be `Map<String, Int?>`, because it `[]` operator returns nullable value. To make sure we do have `Int` type we need to check the returned value is not null. The getValue is more elegant (and it does the check) https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-value.html

Comment: I don't know... this doesn't really look readable to me... you may also want to use [`asSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html) instead of directly using `distinct().mapIndexed`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would solve the problem pretty neatly:

```
val orig = listOf("a", "b", "a", "c")

val positions = orig.distinct().let { uniques ->
    orig.withIndex().associate { (idx, e) -> idx to uniques.indexOf(e) }
}
```

Comment: I think this answer makes way more sense... I would only extract `orig.distinct()` in its own `val distinctValues = orig.distinct()` which makes the code even more readable and I assume that the `distinctValues` are actually required at some point again ... (or I just don't understand the value of such a map ;-))